# How to hide a menu after clicking the Link using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to have a website menu, but after I am redirected by it 
to the correct page, I want the menu to disappear.
I manage to implement it using react-router-dom and useLocation as described bellow,
but I honestly feel there is a better way of doing it, since I dont like using the "/" as a constant...
do any one has a better idea?

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {get} from 'lodash'

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";


const MenuWrapper = (props) => {
    let location = useLocation()
    if (get(location, 'pathname') === '/') {
        return (<div className={props.className}>{props.children}</div>)
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

const Page = styled.div`

`

const MenuBox = styled(MenuWrapper)`
  `;

const MenuButton = styled(Link)`
  `;

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <Page>
            <Router>
                <MenuBox>
                    <MenuButton to={'/someURL'}>play against computer</MenuButton>
                    <MenuButton to={'/home'}>Home</MenuButton>
                </MenuBox>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={'/someURL'}><PlayRandomMoveEngine/></Route>
                    <Route path={'/home'}>
                        <div/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </Page>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please let me know why you downvote. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try alternative way for inserting MenuBox to app. Follow to the code below

```js
const Router = () {
  return (
    <Page>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <HomePage>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/someURL">
            <PlayRandomMoveEngine/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

HomePage.js

```js
import MenuBox from '~/components/MenuBox';

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MenuBox>
        <MenuButton to="/someURL">play against computer</MenuButton>
        <MenuButton to={'/home'}>Home</MenuButton>
      </MenuBox>
      <div> HOME PAGE ! </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

as a result you will see the MenuBox only by the next path "/". And if you decides to show menu on some other page with some other menu items it's not a problem. Just import MenuBox and it will work fine

Comment: worked. for some reason I thought the Links has to be outside of the the <Switch>, clearly I didnt understand the mechanism good enough - thanks!